# Azure Devops Customize Email Notifications

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops comes with notifications.  You can customize the individuals that are notified and when.

Does anyone know of a way to customize what the release section notification says? I have a need to have all the build commit numbers in the release email.  I know the build notification email has the commits but the Release currently doesn't out of the box.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot customize email templates in cloud-hosted Azure DevOps.

Comment: I had an inkling that this was the case.  To the suggestion box I go!  Thank you.